# How can I go to implementation of a Thrift service implementation on IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I open a java micro-service project with IDEA. There are 3 modules: AServer, AClient, B, module AClient has thrift service interfaces, module AServer has the implementations of thrift service interfaces in AClient. Module B invoke thrift interfaces of A.

Previously, when I use "go to implementations" feature of IDEA on invocation statements of module B, it can navigate to the implementation class in AServer module. I don't know what happens, now when I click ⌥⌘B, it only shows the generated java codes in AClient, but not the real implementations in AServer, how can I make it "go to implementation" class in AServer?

Answer (score 0):

When you commit your Aservice Jar which used in Bservice you should commit the source code to the maven  repository.In Aservice’s pom.xml add tag distributionManagement.
Then download the source code for Bservice’s dependence jars